# Unable to read a text file into jupyter notebook on mac

Tags: python, macos, pandas, text-files, jupyter-notebook

I downloaded [this dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data) and stored it in a folder called `AutomobileDataset`.

1. I cross checked the working directory using:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   import os

   os.chdir("/Users/madan/Desktop/ML/Datasets/AutomobileDataset")
   os.getcwd()
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   '/Users/madan/Desktop/ML/Datasets/AutomobileDataset'
   ```
2. Then I tried reading the file using pandas:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   import os

   os.chdir("/Users/madan/Desktop/ML/Datasets/AutomobileDataset")
   os.getcwd()

   automobile_data = pd.read_csv("AutomobileDataset.txt", sep = ',',
                                 header = None, na_values = '?')

   automobile_data.head()
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 26
   ```

Someone please help me with this, I don't know where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty re reformat your question a little so it is more readable. If you indent code by four spaces (or eight in lists) it will be displayed in a code block (mono space font and syntax highlighting).

Comment: what line is the error?

Comment: Can you open the file in Excel or other spreadsheet program? If so, look for any corrupted characters in the first couple lines. If you see corrupted lines, try re-downloading the file, saving it straight from the browser as `.csv` instead of `.txt`.

Comment: Thanks that helped to read the file because i saved from the browser directly as .csv.                                                                                       Another factor was there are actually two formats in which we can save the file one is "webarchive" and other is "page source".I chose page source and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Can try this!

```
import os

# Read in a plain text file
with open(os.path.join("c:user/xxx/xx", "xxx.txt"), "r") as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)
```